# What must the determinant of B equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are $4 \times  4$ matrices such that
$$\det(A) = −2$$

and .
$$\det(3A^T(B^2)^{-1})=2.$$

What must the $\det B$ equal?

I have tried to do this question by getting to

$$2 = 3^. \det(A^T) \det(B^2)^{-1},$$

but i am not too sure if that is right, like maybe the $3$ go to the $4$-th power because it is in a $4 \times 4$ matrix.

Comment: Do you know what happens to the determinant of a matrix when you take its transpose? What about when you square it? What about the determinant of its inverse?

Comment: the determinant stays the same when transpose, when squaring it you get the determinant times the determinant again and the inverse would be 1/determinant

Answer (score 1):

You're going well:
$$
2=3^4\det(A^T)\det((B^2)^{-1})
$$
Now recall that $\det(X^T)=\det(X)$ and $\det((X)^{-1})=(\det(X))^{-1}$, so you end up with
$$
2=3^4\det(A)(\det(B))^{-2}
$$

Comment: how else would you continue to solve?

Comment: i got an answer of 9, but im not too sure if i did it right or wrong.

Comment: @JohnChen From $(\det B)^2=81$ one gets two solutions.

Comment: so it would be +/- 9?

Comment: @JohnChen Yes, you can’t be more precise than that.

Comment: i was wondering how someone would get -root 3 as their final answer? that is what my professor got as an answer and it doesnt match up with mines

Comment: @JohnChen Oh, I overlooked that $\det(A)=-2$. Thus you get $2=-2\cdot3^4(\det(B))^{-2}$, so $(\det(B))^2=-3^4$, which is impossible if the matrices have real entries. You are right: if $X$ is a $4\times4$ matrix and $a$ is a scalar, then $\det(aX)=a^4\det(X)$.